# Using lists of patterns to code a new field

Tags: r, grepl

I want to use lists of expressions to code a new field.

In my dataframe, Bisaccategory1 contains a full description of a book category. Specific strings representing partial values in this field can be used to define a new field called "Genre". One particular Genre would be "nonfiction", which maps to 25 unique full descriptions. I can identify these full descriptions by specifying certain patterns that are contained within them:

```
  nonfiction<-c("BIOGRAPHY & AUTOBIOGRAPHY","BODY, MIND & SPIRIT","BUSINESS & ECONOMICS","COMICS & GRAPHIC NOVELS",
                  "COMPUTERS","COOKING","FAMILY & RELATIONSHIPS","HEALTH & FITNESS","HISTORY","HOUSE & HOME","HUMOR",
                  "LITERARY CRITICISM","NATURE","PERFORMING 
ARTS","PETS","PHOTOGRAPHY","POETRY","POLITICAL SCIENCE","RELIGION",
                      "SCIENCE","SELF-HELP","SOCIAL SCIENCE","SPORTS & RECREATION","TRANSPORTATION","TRUE CRIME")
```

I can then match these strings to complete Biscategory1 values as follows:

```
matches <- unique (grep(paste(nonfiction,collapse="|"), 
                                detail$Bisaccategory1, value=TRUE))
```

But I'm unclear about how to use these "matches" to assign the value "nonfiction" to my new genre field.

This is the sample data:

```
structure(list(Author = c("James Swallow", "Billy Crystal", "Mark Divine", 
"Charles Cumming", "Victoria Schwab", "Louise Penny", "Elizabeth Warren", 
"Linda Castillo", "Paul Fischer", "Sandy Hall", "Louise Penny", 
"Louise Penny", "Lisa Scottoline", "Linda Castillo", "Evan Osnos", 
"Porter Erisman"), Title = c("24: Deadline", "700 Sundays - Still Foolin' 'Em", 
"8 Weeks to Sealfit", "A Colder War", "A Dark Shade of Magic", 
"A Fatal Grace", "A Fighting Chance", "A Hidden Secret", "A Kim Jong-Il Production", 
"A Little Something Different", "A Rule Against Murder", "A Trick of the Light", 
"Accused", "After the Storm", "Age of Ambition", "Alibaba's World"
), Bisac = c("FICTION / Thrillers / General", "BIOGRAPHY & AUTOBIOGRAPHY / Entertainment & Performing Arts", 
"HEALTH & FITNESS / Exercise", "FICTION / Thrillers / Espionage", 
"FICTION / Fantasy / Historical", "FICTION / Mystery & Detective / Traditional", 
"BIOGRAPHY & AUTOBIOGRAPHY / Political", "FICTION / Mystery & Detective / Police Procedural", 
"HISTORY / Asia / Korea", "JUVENILE FICTION / Love & Romance", 
"FICTION / Mystery & Detective / Traditional", "FICTION / Mystery & Detective / Traditional", 
"FICTION / Thrillers / Legal", "FICTION / Mystery & Detective / Police Procedural", 
"HISTORY / Asia / China", "BUSINESS & ECONOMICS / E-Commerce / General"
)), .Names = c("Author", "Title", "Bisac"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

I know that I can do something like:

```
df$Genre[Bisaccategory1=="BODY, MIND & SPIRIT / Inspiration & Personal Growth"]<-"nonfiction"
```

but I have hundreds of categories, and this isn't really scalable. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `grep` the function `grepl` will return a logical index where matches were made. You can use that to subset the Genre column. I assigned the entries that were not "non-fiction" to fiction, but you can make them whatever you'd like.

```
matches <- grepl(paste(nonfiction,collapse="|"), detail$Bisac)
detail$Genre <- "fiction"
detail$Genre[matches] <- "non-fiction"
# Bisac       Genre
# 1                                FICTION / Thrillers / General     fiction
# 2  BIOGRAPHY & AUTOBIOGRAPHY / Entertainment & Performing Arts non-fiction
# 3                                  HEALTH & FITNESS / Exercise non-fiction
# 4                              FICTION / Thrillers / Espionage     fiction
# 5                               FICTION / Fantasy / Historical     fiction
# 6                  FICTION / Mystery & Detective / Traditional     fiction
# 7                        BIOGRAPHY & AUTOBIOGRAPHY / Political non-fiction
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)

non_fiction_books = 
  detail %>%
  mutate(Bisac = Bisac %>% stri_split_fixed(" / ") ) %>%
  unnest(Bisac) %>%
  mutate(Bisac = Bisac %>% stri_trans_toupper) %>%
  right_join(data_frame(Bisac = non_fiction) ) %>%
  select(-Bisac) %>%
  distinct
```